How can I link a UNC path on Jazz production server?
When I press "add related artifacts" I want to link a UNC path to a file share on my windows machine. Every method I try gets blocked.
none of these work.
\\fileshare\unc\path\to use\test
http:\\fileshare\unc\path\to use\test
\\fileshare\unc\path\to%20use\test

Figured it out, file://///fileshare/unc/path/to use/test would be the answer, but it is restricted in my web browser regardless of what actually works or not.
